# Change onEdit Google Script to Time Based Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have script set up in Google Sheets which adds a new date to 2 columns when an onEdit change is triggered. Unfortunately the data which should trigger the onEdit function is fed by an API and does not count as an edit according to Google. I need to switch the function to a time based trigger and run it every minute to check. The original onEdit script is below:

```
function declineDate() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getActiveRange();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var value = cell.getValue();
  var col2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1);
  var col3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+2);
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1,1,2);
  if (col == 11 && (value=="Completed"))
    return col2.setValue(new Date());
  else if ((col == 11 && (value=="Declined" || value=="Accepted" || value=="Withdrawn")) && (col2.isBlank()))
    return range.setValue(new Date());
  else if ((col == 11 && (value=="Declined" || value=="Accepted" || value=="Withdrawn")) && (col2 != ""))
    return col3.setValue(new Date());
}
```

A viewable link to the spreadsheet is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nHBIlRDu3MqDhjDd8eTr3mu57_LO4OWQjh7uwDAIMNU/edit?usp=sharing

I need to switch the function so that it runs once a minute (or every few minutes) and loops through the rows, adding in the relevant dates to columns 12 and 13 depending on the Status column (col 11). Ideally the loop would only run on rows if Column 2 has data/greater than 0 and Column 13 is blank – so that we're not running through all the backdated rows again.

I am aware that there will need to be some quite significant changes to the current function (seeing as it doesn't work!) and any help would be much appreciated.

Happy to send over any more information if needed.

Thanks a lot

Alex

Comment: Can you change your sheet to Public? It's only showing us 'ask for permission'.

Comment: @noogui apologies – sheet is now public. Thanks!